# Susy: different order of blocks for different breakpoints?

Tags: susy-compass

I would like the header of my site to look like this:

```
[_1_] [____2____] [_3_]
```

On smaller screens, i would like it to adapt like this:

```
[____2____]
[_1_] [_3_]
```

That can easily be achieved with ZenGrids, but i fail to come up with a solution for Susy.

How can i achieve that using Susy's `at-breakpoint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with source order 2-1-3, and then using push/pull to move columns into place. You can also use the `columns()`, `gutter()`, and `space()` functions to manipulate margins by hand - which would allow you to recreate the Zen approach fairly easily.